# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with RTX 3080

Tags: pytorch, python-3.7

Hi~ I just get RTX 3080 and meet lots of version problems. One of them is the problem that pop up “Segmentation fault (core dumped)” and multiprocessing issue.

There is my device list below:

- GPU: RTX 3080
- CPU: Intel i7-10700
- CUDA: 11.1
- RAM: 32GB
- Python: 3.7.5
- Pytorch: 1.7.0.dev20200927+cu110

And the following is the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUGWH.png

Did anyone encounter the same problem? Thanks~~